# Is there any mathematical formula for electron affinity and ionization potential?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electronegativity, ionization-energy, electron-affinity

I already know about the mathematical formula for electronegativity, but it requires the ionization potential and electron affinity. How can I can easily calculate the ionization potential and electron affinity with a mathematical formula?

Comment: You can't.$\mathstrut$

Comment: Technically, you could solve the multi-electron Schrodinger equation and compute the energy difference, but I believe that is an intractable problem without at least severe approximations.

Comment: @Zhe one such severe approximation is to solve the Schrodinger equation using the Hartree Fock approximation, then assume frozen orbitals for the ionization process. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koopmans'_theorem